# Proving that a subgroup is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra

When we want to prove that a subgroup is normal, we usually show that the left and right cosets are equal, right? But what if a group has so many elements, is not abelian, and the subgroup does not have index 2...how can we show that such a subgroup is normal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a specific example in mind?

Comment: This question is much too open-ended to admit a conclusive answer, like asking how one proves theorems or evaluates integrals. You can of course ask for generic or standard techniques that can usually be relied upon for elementary cases.

Comment: @anon and Zev Chonoles Actually, I do have a specific example in mind. I just thought that asking a general question would be enough...I was thinking of the group $Gl_2(Z_3)$ and wanted to prove that a subgroup H is normal in that group. |H|=8 and the elements are here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310715/a-subgroup-of-operatornamegl-2-mathbbz-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One particular way is to choose a set of generators for the group and subgroup. One can do this for infinite groups, but I'll focus on the case of finite groups.

A set of generators $A = \{a_1^{\pm}, a_2^{\pm}, \dots, a_n^{\pm}\}$ (where $\pm$ denotes the element and its inverse) for a group $G$ are elements $a_i \in G$ (and their inverses) such that when you take all possible ``words'' in $A$, you can get all the elements of $G$. In other words, any $g \in G$ can be written as $g = a_{i_1}a_{i_2}\dots a_{i_m}$, where $a_{i_k} \in A$ and you can have as many repetitions as you want, and each of the $a_{i_k}$ can refer to any $a_i \in A$ and its inverse.

Let's say then that $A$ generates $G$ and that a subset $B$ generates a subgroup $H$, and you want to check whether that subgroup is normal. Let's also assume that the normalizer of $B$ in $G$ is $G$, i.e., $N_G(B) = \{g \in G : gB = Bg\} = G$ (* -- check note at bottom) -- this amounts to saying that $B$ is a ``normal subset''. Then, for any $g \in G$, $h \in H$,

\begin{align*}
ghg^{-1} &= gb_1b_2\dots b_n g^{-1} \tag{because B generates H} \\
&= gb_1 g^{-1}g b_2 \dots g b_ng^{-1} \\
&= \beta_1\beta_2\dots \beta_n
\end{align*}
where the $\beta_i \in B$ since $B$ is ``normal''. Since $B \subset H$ you have shown that it suffices to normality of $H$ on a set of generators of $H$. You should show that it suffices to use elements $a_i \in G$ instead of all $g$.

(*) check out the definitions of normalizer, centralizer and stabilizer. These will provide you with a way of thinking about groups that should guide the general ``philosophical'' answer to your question.

Comment: What you describe in the first paragraph is a set of generators for the underlying monoid. You should add inverses. For example, $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $1$ as a group, but not as a monoid.

Comment: Crap, you are absolutely right, that slipped my mind, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways of showing a subgroup is normal. One would be to show that the subgroup is the kernel of some homomorphism. There are some general theorems that guarantee a subgroup of a finite group to be normal, by some combinatorial argument. For instance, if $H$ has index $p$ and $p$ is the smallest prime that divides $|G|$, then $H$ must be normal. (This extends the easy result that a subgroup of index $2$ is normal).

So, when given a particular subgroup and asked if it is normal you can try any of a rather limited number of tricks, or resort to (any of the equivalent) definitions of normality.